# HTTP request for details of ActiveMQ active subscribers

Tags: activemq-classic, subscriber

I'm using ActiveMQ 5.16.2. Is there a way to make an HTTP call to get details of the active subscribes? I would like to know such as client ID, connection ID, status, etc.

Comment: It's version 5.16.2

Comment: I think the following link provides me with the info I am looking for. How can I provide a username and password with the link, or no credential is required....  http://hostname:8161/admin/xml/subscribers.jsp

Comment: Check out the "Rest Management" chapter in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/rest.html).

Comment: If you try to use `subscribers.jsp` you're going to get HTML back that you'll have to parse. You would be much better off using Jolokia which was designed for this purpose. See the documentation linked in my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I read the 'Rest Management' section but it doesn't describe details (parameters) to extract a specific subscriber, for instance.

Comment: Use JConsole (or any other GUI JMX tool) and look through the MBeans to find the one that has the information you want. Then you can take the name of that MBean and use it to construct the URL you need for your HTTP/Jolokia command as described in the documentation. It should be pretty straight-forward.